# Group by required even thought i don't want to group by

Tags: sql

The following table has Key and StartTime and EndTime.  I want to my query to return, my key, the number of records with this Key and the total minutes of all records with the same Key. I cant run with out StartTime and EndTime in my group by unfortunately this groups each row with a different start or stop time.

```
SELECT sn.Key, 
        COUNT(*) as SessonNoteCount, 
        sum( dbo.fnCalcTime( sn.StartTime, sn.EndTime)) as min

FROM SessionNote sn 

group by sn.Key,  sn.StartTime, sn.EndTime
order by sn.Key
```

Comment: Why can't you run without the `sn.StartTime` and `sn.EndTime` in the `GROUP BY` clause? It seems to me that you can. However, just so you know, you could get incredibly awful performance with that function in there. If you want to abstract your time calculation using a function and get reasonable performance, it needs to be a `RETURNS TABLE` function that has a single `SELECT` statement in it, created `WITH SCHEMABINDING` and used like `Sum( (SELECT Elapsed FROM dbo.fnCalcTime(sn.STartTime, sn.EndTime)) )`. This will allow the parser to inline the function body.

Answer (score 0):

You should group by all non-aggregated selected columns, which in your case is just `sn.Key`:

```
group by sn.Key
```

---

As an aside, IMHO the group by clause should be optional because it is entirely determined by the column selected columns and could easily be generated by the query parser, but that boat has sailed...